# Mechanism of improved version of Howard's algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

For [Efficient algorithms for optimum cycle mean and optimum cost to time ratio problems](http://www.cecs.uci.edu/%7Epapers/compendium94-03/papers/1999/dac99/pdffiles/02_4.pdf#page=4) , could anyone advise how the following Howard's algorithm works to compute minimum mean cycle path ?

[image: Howard's algorithm]

Comment: Doesn’t the paper explain it? Do you have any specific confusions?

Comment: @Eric Why use reverse BFS ?